# Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array Using HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

**Can Anyone help with what's wrong with my code?**

```
class Solution {
public int removeDuplicates(int[] nums) {
    HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
  for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
      hs.add(nums[i]);
  }
    Iterator<Integer> it = hs.iterator();
    int n = 0;
    while(it.hasNext()){
        n = it.next();
    }
    return n;
}
```

}

**Your input
[1,1,2]
Output
[1,1]
Diff
Expected
[1,2]**

Comment: if it sorted array you can do it without hash set

Comment: Why does your code return int? Shouldn't it return the hashset it creates?

Comment: What is doing this "output"?  The return value from the method certainly is not [1,1] in any representation.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit like a man that walks into a forest and stars chopping down a tree.

As the tree falls, the man says: "Why isn't my bread rising?"

Because you're doing something **completely** different.

This code:

- Adds every item in a provided number array to a set.
- Loops through the set in order to overwrite a single variable (`n`) with the value in the set every time, which is a silly thing to do.
- It then returns that number.
- It does **absolutely nothing** with the incoming integer array.
- The number returned doesn't count duplicates.

Just start over. The code you pasted is unrelated to the job description, so the only way to interpret this question is 'please write a method that removes duplicates for me' which I think is beyond the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, that's a little harsh to a beginner. Loading the array into a Set isn't a bad idea, though as written it's going to run afoul if the result is to be sorted. However, from there is goes to hell....